# How to make Feathers for a Gladiator Helmet with Particle Hair?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles

I have here my wip of a Gladiator helmet and I would like to know how to set up a hair particle system to a point that I would like to achieve. And of course I would like to know how to make a good looking cycles material for it.

Here are some reference images and a screenshot of my mesh.

[image: reference]

[image: my mesh]

[image: reference]

Comment: i dont know at all what i can do is just click on create and switch to hair i dont now how todo so the hairparticles have a nice curve and not the default and i dont know at all wat vlaues i should use in root and tip and so on.

Comment: Note that these kinds of questions are controversial, see http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/476/should-we-expand-our-scope-to-allow-simple-howtos

Comment: And http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62/regarding-questions-and-answers-as-tutorials

Comment: yes make youre scope bigger when the answer isnt to complicated.

Comment: I don't think a Thracian helmet would have feather quite like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

I would use a separate mesh for the emission of the hair particles. This allows for more flexibility and ease of customizing the hair later.

1. Add something like this on top of the helmet to act as the hair emitter:

   [image]

   You might want to separate part of the helmet mesh to ensure that there are no gaps between the emitter mesh and the actual helmet object. You might even want to put the emitter a little bit inside the helmet, just to be extra safe.
2. Add a particle system and change the *type* to hair (1). Also disable *emitter* so that the emitter object doesn't appear in the render (2), and enable child particles (3).  I used *interpolated* child particles, but this depends a bit on what you want to do.
   Note that *Simple* child particles can result in floating hairs if you are not careful, especially on curved surfaces.

   [image]

   Note that I also tweaked the child particle settings to add a bit of randomness, so that the hairs are not all perfectly straight.
3. Add a material to the emitter. I used a simple translucent material:

   [image]
4. Back in the particle settings of the emitter object, tweak the thickness and scale of the hairs as desired. You'll have to play with these settings a bit to get a feel for how they affect the render, but it should be pretty intuitive for the most part (e.g. thicker hairs will make it so less light can get through, making the hair appear more dense/dark in the render)

   I went with a more uniform hair thickness, only tapering the thickness a little bit towards the ends of the hairs:

   [image]

[**Example .blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32055)

Comment: lol dude that looks really great you da MVP.